# Partial page updates with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am building an AngularJS application that has a sidebar and a main content area. Both are populated by separate invocations of the $http service to retrieve some JSON data. The stuff in the sidebar is basically a table of contents and the intent is that clicking on one of the sidebar items will cause the main area to be updated.

My initial stab at this involved putting the sidebar and main area into one partial and then associating it with a controller that does both retrievals. The application has a route that associates the controller to a URL, and the links in the sidebar access these URL with the appropriate parameter that will cause the desired content to appear in the main area. All this works, but it does cause the whole page to refresh. The "partial" really is a "total".

What I'd like to do is somehow cause a click on the sidebar links to trigger a refresh of the main content area only. One thought is to somehow split it into two controller/partial pairs and figure out a way to cause sidebar clicks to request an update. I'm not sure about the mechanics of doing this, though. Another approach is to keep the stuff in one controller and use some kind of shared state that would trigger this update. I attempted to do this by setting an ng-click directive on the links, but this did not update a scope variable, as I had hoped.

Is there a recommended way of structuring an application to achieve this kind of AJAX-driven partial page update? It seems like a fairly common case, but I haven't mastered enough of AngularJS to get a solution.

Comment: Are you familiar with the `ng-view` directive?

Comment: Sounds like you havn't set up hashbang url's or html5 mode if your page does a full refresh.. also as @JosephSilber said, read up on ng-view

Answer (score 8):

This is what I'm doing:

I have 2 services, 1 for the sidemenu and the other for the main content. They are both injected into the controller.

To handle cross service calls I use `$broadcast` to send events.

Works really well and is very clean code.

**additional info on using services based on comment**

For the sidemenu i have a shared menu service, that way all controllers can use the same menu.

The maincontent service doesnt have to be shared, but i use them because services don't loose their data when the controller goes out of scope.  If I didn't the controller would have to use some other mechanism to repopulate its data.  For me a service handles it without having to code anything

To show the different views i use the following main layout html

```
<div >
    <!-- left menu -->
    <div id="left" ng-include src="menu.view" ></div>

    <!-- main content -->
    <div id="main" ng-include src="maincontent.view"></div>
</div>
```

the controller

```
function myControllerCtrl($scope, $rootScope, menuService, maincontentService) {
    $scope.menu = menuService;
    $scope.maincontent = mainContentService
}
```

the menu service

```
app.factory('menuService', ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
    var service = {
        view: 'leftmenuview.html',

        MenuItemClicked: function (data) {
            $rootScope.$broadcast('menuitemclicked', data);
        }
    };
    return service;
}]);
```

the main content service

```
app.factory('maincontentService', ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
    var service = {
        view: 'maincontentview.html',

        MenuItemClicked: function(data){
          //handle updating of model based on data here
        }
    };

    $rootScope.$on('menuitemclicked', function (event, data) { service.MenuItemClicked(data) });

    return service;
}]);
```

Comment: That was me, and it was a mistake. Wanted to click to upvote. Sorry. Now that I realized my mistake, it wouldn't let me change it anymore, unless you make an edit to your post.

Comment: I made a small edit to your post, so that I can revert the vote.

Comment: I think I understand the injection part, but can you explain the two services? I've seen references to services, but I think it was in the context of the app creating a single "shared" service injected into two different controllers. This seems to be the "inverse" of that technique. Where are the services defined and what does each one do?

Comment: @user2643044,  services can be shared. for the sidemenu i have a shared menu service, that way all controllers can use the same menu. the maincontent service doesnt have to be shared, but i use them because services don't loose their data when the controller goes out of scope.

Comment: @Anton, this sounds pretty close to what I'm after. It sounds like your app splits this into (at least) two controllers, sidebar and main. Is there a partial for each one, and if so, what AngularJS directives cause both of them to be loaded? Also, is your service declared up in the module declaration?

Comment: Directives aren't needed, i am using ng-include. I added the code to the answer. I cut and pasted it with edits to make it as concise as i can.  hopefully i havent added any typos.

Comment: Are the two services responsible for doing the queries that populate the two areas, or does that remain in the controller? Also, I'm still not clear on the mechanism by which a value that gets changed over in the sidebar gets transmitted to the main area and triggers a new download. There seems to be a lot of implicit behavior and I've not been able to tease out how to set things up so that data flows.

Comment: yes the services are responsible for everything that is associated with themselves, so they hold the model data and are responsible for populating the model data. The menu service uses $rootscope.$broadcast('menuitemclicked',data) and the maincontentservice listens with $rootscope.$on('menuitemclicked',fn()) where fn() loads the data. i've added the broadcast stuff to the answer

Comment: Just so I understand - this solution doesn't change the route, and therefore these clicks are not being added to the history, and the "back" button doesn't do anything - is that right?  Not a criticism just a question.

Comment: the way i am using it the clicks dont add to the history because i'm not changing the pages url, just the data and views showing.  if you do change the url and the route, then it will be added to the history.